# BlazeDS binary latest version download location

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-flex, transactions, flex4

I am trying to download blazeDS to integrate my future Adobe Flex application with Java Web app all links I found come from [this site](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/blazeds/wiki/Home/) and point to Adobe's website which in turn point back to the former.

Were can I get the binary blazeDS jar/war? i don't whant th source-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe dropped the development of Flex but luckly the framework is updated by the Apache Fundation:

http://flex.apache.org/download-blazeds.html

You can download the executable version (old version) from here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6l2NgAntvfNT20wNDdVUHNqekk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: as i said before i don't want the source file like in the link you provided. because there are some build error like "No marketplace entries found to handle javacc-maven-plugin:2.5:javacc in Eclipse" i want the jar not the project

Comment: If you want I can provide you a link to download the 4.6 version (should be equal to the 4.7 minus a little difference as said here `http://it.apache.contactlab.it/flex/BlazeDS/4.7.0/RELEASE_NOTES`... It is the version I'm using I need time to get the package and upload to a server... Also I need to check if I am not breaking any license stuff...

Comment: please upload it to me i will do with this

Comment: i found also where i can download previous trunk versions with some samples and documentations http://sourceforge.net/adobe/blazeds/wiki/download%20blazeds%20trunk/

Answer (score 1):

Or just could just grab the latest Version 4.7.2. (in Dec 2016) from mvnrepository.com here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flex.blazeds

You can grab each JAR by selecting the artifact and clicking on "Download (JAR)".

If you have a maven project, you can just add the following dependencies to the pom.xml:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flex.blazeds/flex-messaging-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flex.blazeds</groupId>
    <artifactId>flex-messaging-common</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flex.blazeds/flex-messaging-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flex.blazeds</groupId>
    <artifactId>flex-messaging-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flex.blazeds/flex-messaging-proxy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flex.blazeds</groupId>
    <artifactId>flex-messaging-proxy</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.2</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flex.blazeds/flex-messaging-remoting -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flex.blazeds</groupId>
    <artifactId>flex-messaging-remoting</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```